# is it possible to insert a complete json array into single mysql record

Tags: php, mysql, json

I would like to insert a json object array into a single mysql record as longtext but not sure this is possible.

The json response is this:-

```
stdClass Object
(
    [name] => Alex Xxx
    [title] => Head of Something
    [picture] => https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/d19553c39a6b7d48decd50b3fe84a431?s=80&d=404
    [location] => Slough, United Kingdom
    [images] => Array
        (
            [0] => https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/d19553c39a6b71?s=80&d=404
            [1] => http://m3.licdn.com/mpr/360b418.jpg
        )

    [provider] => srptv
    [email] => alex.xx@xx.com
)
```

I'd like to add this as text into the record. I've tried this but it only inserts a number 1 in the field.

```
$apiresult = mysql_real_escape_string(print_r(json_decode($jsonresponse)));
$mysql = "UPDATE `test` SET `first_api_pass_response`  = '$apiresult' WHERE `data_content` = '$data_content'";
$addresults = mysql_query($mysql);
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Jonathan

Comment: Why don't you insert the json in the database, and convert it when you need to output the data?

Comment: Also print_r needs `true` as second argument to return with the data as string. `$apiresult = mysql_real_escape_string(print_r(json_decode($jsonresponse), true));`

Comment: BTW try switching to mysqli_* or PDO as mysql_* are no longer maintained

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`print_r` prints direct - you need to use

```
$apiresult = mysql_real_escape_string(print_r(json_decode($jsonresponse),1));
```

to make `print_r` return the output to the variable

http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php the second argument is a return argument

Answer (score 3):

Just save it as a JSON in the database.

```
$apiresult = mysql_real_escape_string($jsonresponse);
$mysql = "UPDATE `test` SET `first_api_pass_response`  = '$apiresult' WHERE `data_content` = '$data_content'";
$addresults = mysql_query($mysql);
```

And retrieve it when you output the data (I'm assuming `$row` is your retrieved row in a loop or something):

```
json_decode($row['first_api_pass_response']);
```